# Increment the value of a pointer when sent as a parameter

Tags: c++, c, pointers, microcontroller

I am stuck in the following pointer problem:

Say you have a function:

```
void Function (unsigned char *ubPointer)
{
    ubPointer++;
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned char *PointerX;

    Function( PointerX );
}
```

What I want is that the ++ is reflected in PointerX, without declaring it as a global variable.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Andy is 100% correct, but what he didn't say explicitly is that you are passing the pointer *by value*. In C, everything is passed by value, so if you wish to mutate the argument of a function, you must add another level of indirection (i.e., a pointer to pointer in this case).  C++ allows for references, which are conceptually similar, but guarantee that the reference is not null.  C and C++ are different languages.  You should specify which it is you are interested in as the answer will be different.

Comment: @Ed: Damn, I knew there was something I forgot to write ;) Very good point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++, pass your pointer *by reference* (and don't forget to specify a return type for your function):

```
void Function (unsigned char*& ubPointer)
//                           ^
{
    ubPointer++;
}
```

This won't require any further change in the calling code. When returning from the function, the side-effects on `ubPointer` will be visible to the caller.

In C, you can achieve the equivalent result by passing a *pointer* to your pointer:

```
void Function (unsigned char** ubPointer)
//                           ^
{
    (*ubPointer)++;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

This will require you to change the way you are calling your function:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char* p;
    Function(&p);
    //       ^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to do it C-style

```
void Function (unsigned char **ubPointer)
{
    (*ubPointer)++;
}
```

because

```
Function (unsigned char **ubPointer)
{
    ubPointer++;
}
```

would be increasing the address pointed to.

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be `**`?

Comment: Why do you think that? The function's signature states that it is a pointer. You dereference a pointer using `*`. If you don't believe it, try it yourself.

Comment: I may be too tired, but I think that'd deference it to a `char` and increment that letter.

Comment: @teppic is right - this doesn't answer the question, i.e. how to modify the parameter.

Comment: Yeah, so? `char` is handled like `int`, so it would produce the next character. Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think you do need `**`, as the function needs to change a pointer.

Comment: Okay, I checked... Made a mistake! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

```
void Function (unsigned char *ubPointer)
{
    (*ubPointer)++;  
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned char *PointerX;

    Function( PointerX );
}
```

This is the correction

Comment: This increments the character `ubPointer[0]`, *not* the pointer `PointerX` like the OP asked. See the other answers for the right way to do it.